# Should I edit old answers to improve them?

Tags: discussion

I recently had a comment on a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692192/resize-boot-in-lvm/692201?noredirect=1692201#692201) that I posted about a year ago. Now, how I thought Ask Ubuntu works was that you answer, and your answer stays. Even if it is three years ago, you don't need to edit your answer (no matter how bad it is). Of course there are cases where links change and you need to change them. I didn't think suggestions (like the one on my answer) would come (a year later).

My question is, is it good practice to hunt down those old posts from myself and improve my (bad) answers (since I know a little more than when I joined Ask Ubuntu)?

Maybe even posts from other users too?

Comment: It's always good to improve the site's quality. One way is by posting great new questions and answers, the other way is by cleaning up old (and not so old) low quality posts. If a rather bad post was unnoticed for a longer period of time, that doesn't really make it better, i.e. the same quality standards still apply and action should be taken accordingly.

Comment: Try to aim to make answers not time limited.

Comment: @ByteCommander For myself, I struggle sometimes to bring good questions. The question I ask are usually beginner to semi-intermediate. I really want to ask those nice questions, but I sometimes can't(because I don't know any) or too afraid because of downvotes. I really do want to make AskUbuntu better. Also, I know how I am not supposed to change the meaning of rep, but sometimes it hits somewhere its not supposed to and you just change from there.

Comment: @Rinzwind Do you mean that I should take my time in answering questions? Some posts today, I come three months later and post an answer? I find it bizarre when a post from 2010 gets a new answer this year when sometimes the answers have already been accepted. When I am checking questions to answer, I usually treat and help the OP as quickly as possible. Sometimes, that makes me crash, *hard*.

Comment: It likely means that someone ran into the same problem while searching on Google and answered. Think of AU more as a pile of interlinked wiki pages more than a forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How I see it, agreeing completely with [Byte Commander's comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16333/old-answers-from-users/16334#comment32661_16333): I try to constantly check through all my posts (maybe one or two a day) and see if I can improve them.

If I see any other post anywhere I can improve, however old, I try (respectfully) to improve it, unless I think it should be deleted. The site as it is, as a whole and in all its parts, should be as good as possible, and I should make it as good as I can, and that's all.